# Can't forward request to netty server running on virtualbox

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I am running a netty server using the play framework and sbt inside a Fedora VirtualBox VM.

The netty server is bound to 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces:

```
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9081
```

Port forwarding for the Fedora VM is configured to forward from host: 127.0.0.1 and port: 9081 to guest ip : 10.0.2.15 and port: 9081

However, when I request localhost:9081 on a web browser on my host, it keeps loading and never seems to reach the server.

The netty server is responding fine if I issue a request from inside the VM.

I have another http server similarly configured which is working fine. I don't know what I need to change to make the netty server reachable from the host.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was the firewall that was blocking access from outside the VM:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=9081/tcp
```